# Unable to see Rinkeby balance in Geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby

I set up a node on the Rinkeby test network and connect to it with the following command.

```
geth --rinkeby
```

Once this is up and running, I connect to the corresponding console with

```
geth --rinkeby attach
```

I already created an account and requested Ether to it via *faucet.rinkeby.io*. Also I checked, that this account has the correct balance via *rinkeby.etherscan.io*.
My problem is, that I cannot see that balance when using the geth console connected to Rinkeby. I am using the following command in order to check the balance, which always retrives 0.

```
eth.getBalance("myAccountsHash")
```

Many previous post assume, that the reason for this is, that I am out of sync with the network. But I am not, according to this info (my account received Ether during block 7903687):

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 7904237,
  highestBlock: 7904364,
  knownStates: 29412402,
  pulledStates: 29392902,
  startingBlock: 7904202
}
```

So why do I not receive the correct balance for this account in the geth console?

What is strange is, that while above indicates, that I am nearly in sync with the network, when I execute the following, I receive 0.

```
eth.blockNumber
```

Comment: hello @sebastian-dine. I am also facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: unfortunately no